connection wifi - mediatek 7902
hi I just installed the latest ubuntu LTS on my acer aspire 3 and I don't have access to wifi, after several hours of searching I found absolutely nothing, I use a mediatek 7902 network card

Unfortunately there is no support in Linux for that wifi device

rfkill list would list your card if it worked and had proper driver/firmware.
But in this case, it seems you're out of luck.
https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:14c3-7902-1a3b-5520
From there I see 2 solutions:

buy another wifi card (to replace it internally, or maybe USB?)
if this is not an option, follow this user's instructions: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-wireless-networking-41/mediatek-mt7902-wireless-driver-support-for-linux-4175728598/#post6516756

Hope this helps
